# How To Showing data Datatables Laravel With HasMany

Tags: laravel, datatables, relationship, has-many, relation

This is My Controller
I want to display data looping but when it is displayed only one appears
where's the problem , please help , and give me solution to solved this problem

```
if(empty($search)){
                $jobData = SrvJobSop::with('getJobSopFileMap')
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
            }else{
                $jobData =  SrvJobSop::where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                ->offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                ->get();

                $totalFiltered =  SrvJobSop::where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                ->count();
            }

            $data = [];
            if(count($jobData) > 0){
                foreach($jobData as $num => $jobsop){
                    $currentData = [];
                    $currentData['no'] = $num+1;
                    $currentData['sop_code'] = $jobsop->sop_code;
                    $currentData['name'] = $jobsop->name;
                    $currentData['vehicle_brand_id'] = $jobsop->getVehicleBrand->name;
                    $currentData['vehicle_model_id'] = $jobsop->getVehicleModel->name;
                    $currentData['vehicle_type_id'] = $jobsop->getVehicleType->name;
                    $currentData['year_id'] = $jobsop->getYear->name;
                        foreach($jobsop->getJobSopFileMap as $p){
                            $currentData['file'] = $p->file;
                        }
                    $currentData['machine_type_id'] = $jobsop->getMachineType->name;
                    $currentData['machine_type_id'] = $jobsop->getMachineType->name;
                    $currentData['created_at']      = date('d F Y h:m:s',strtotime($jobsop->created_at));
                    $currentData['created_by_user_id']     = $jobsop->getCreatedByUserId->name;
                    $currentData['opsi'] = "
                    <a href=".url('/carfix-workshop-operation-module/job-sop/form?id='.encrypt($jobsop->srv_job_sop_id)).".  class='btn btn-success btn-xs fa fa-pencil-square-o'
                    title='Edit Data'></a>

                    <a onclick=deleteData('".encrypt($jobsop->srv_job_sop_id)."') class='btn btn-danger btn-xs fa fa-trash-o'
                    title='Delete Data'></a>";

                    $data[] = $currentData;
                }[enter image description here][1]
            }
```

I want to Looping the File name 
how to do that , is my code right ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Newer Laravel @RossWilson